# CSS - Display Child Element Below Parent Element (i.e., Stacked like Rows)

Tags: css, flexbox, nested

sorry if duplicate, I couldn't find this specific thing. Having brain freeze trying to figure something out.

Have a nested set of DIVs that sets a background image on parent, then deepest grandchild is h1 title that sits over the image.

- I need the nested title to sit below the parent (i.e., like rows, not in the 3D z-index sense). The title should be in natural flow so all content below this block is pushed down accordingly. Markup is dynamic and cannot be changed.

```
<div class="parent background-image">
    <div class="1 header-content">
        <div class="2 headers-layout">
            <div class="3 title-bar">
                <div class="4 headers-wrap">
                    <h1 class="5 headers-title">This is the page title</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
    CURRENT/DEFAULT CSS:
    
    .parent {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        height: 100%;
        background-image: url(image.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
    }
    .headers-layout {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .headers-wrap {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

- OPTIONS?

Tried position:absolute, but it needs to sit below the entire parent, and still push remaining content down naturally.

Think it's Flex, but my brain can't figure out with so much nesting, and no 'sibling' elements.

Comment: Do you want something on image or not ?

Answer (score 1):

One way to make the parent plus title push the remaining content down 'naturally' is to give the parent a bottom margin and place the title in that with position absolute.

To make it responsive but still readable this snippet sets the margin and font-size dimensions relative to viewport height but puts a minimum value on them so they keep something readable for the h1 font however small the viewport.

You will obviously want to play with those dimensions to get the required look.

```css
/* the container is just for demo so you can see it in the SO snippet system */

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 80vh;
}

.parent {
  rdisplay: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin-bottom: max(64px, 10vh);
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1016/1024/768);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.headers-layout {
  width: 100%;
}

.headers-wrap {
  z-index: 1;
}

.headers-title {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: max(32px, 5vh);
  top: 100%;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent background-image">
    <div class="1 header-content">
      <div class="2 headers-layout">
        <div class="3 title-bar">
          <div class="4 headers-wrap">
            <h1 class="5 headers-title">This is the page title</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>Stuff following after</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good start, especially with the variable margin & font-size. But with the titles potentially varying in length by such a great deal, it would be so tough to have any consistency with the bottom margin as the title could break to multiple lines at any variable width depending on how long it was. So a giant bottom margin might be necessary for titles breaking to multiple lines, but would look terrible for short, one-line titles.

Comment: Yes, sadly I feel a bit of JS would be needed to decide on the amount to be allocated and that would have to be done on any resize (or you could really really cheat and put the header content as content in pseudo element, but of course that wouldn't work if there was more than just otherwise unstyled text and is terrible for accessibility so ignore this fantasy!).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I have renamed your class name from `2 headers-layout` to simply `headers-layout` and for others also.

From what I have understand from your question, you can use the following code.

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="title-bar">
     <h1 class="headers-title">This is the page title</h1>  
   </div>        
</div>

<div class="content">
   <div class="header-content">
        header-content
   </div>
   <div class="headers-layout">
        headers-layout
   </div>
   <div class="title-bar">
        titlebar
   </div>
   <div class="headers-wrap">
        headers-wrap
   </div>
</div>
```

I have added text on each div for reference.

CSS

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    height: 50%;
      padding:10% 30%;
    background-image: url(https://www.qries.com/images/banner_logo.png);
    background-size: 600px;
}

.content {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    align-content:normal;
    justify-content:normal;
    align-items:normal;
}

.header-content {
    background-color:yellow;
 }
.headers-layout {
      background-color: lightblue;
 }
.title-bar {
    background-color:lightgreen;
    font-weight:700;
 }
.headers-wrap {
    background-color: lightblue;
 }
```

You can modify as per your use case now.

Comment: Yeah, if I could change the markup this would be a piece of cake. But as the markup is dynamically generated, I have to deal with what I have and try to see if I can modify strictly through CSS (well, I'm sure there 'might' be a way to alter programmatically, but it's beyond the scope of this project). And the class numbers were only added to help see the nesting level easier for this example, they're not actually used.